# javascript expand/collapse button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a toggle content button that loads with the content already hidden.
This is the code I'm using but I'm not sure how to make the content appear as hidden (making the toggle button function more used for expanding content)

```js
$(function() {
  var b = $("#button");
  var w = $("#wrapper");
  var l = $("#list");
  
  w.height(l.outerHeight(true));

  b.click(function() {
  
    if(w.hasClass('open')) {
      w.removeClass('open');
      w.height(0);
    } else {
      w.addClass('open');
      w.height(l.outerHeight(true));
    }
  
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 200ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Toggle Expand/Collapse</button>
<div id="wrapper" class="open">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1: Simplified Code

You can actually simplify a fair amount by relying on CSS to define the show/hide style, and transitioning on `max-height`, you then simply toggle the addition of e.g. an `open` class to allow the height of the content to expand.

This also maintains **strict separation of concerns**, keeping functionality withiin Javascript and styling within CSS.

```js
$(function() {
  var b = $("#button");
  var w = $("#wrapper");
  var l = $("#list");
  b.click(function() {
    w.toggleClass('open'); /* <-- toggle the application of the open class on click */
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 300ms;
  max-height: 0; /* <---hide by default */
}
#wrapper.open {
  max-height: 100px; /* <---when open, allow content to expand to take up as much height as it needs, up to e.g. 100px */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Toggle Expand/Collapse</button>
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### Option 2: Revised Code

Alternatively, if you wish to use your existing code, you need to change it so the default state is `hidden`. Do this by setting the `height` to zero in your CSS, removing the `open` class from your HTML and removing the initial height setting from your Javascript:

```js
$(function() {
  var b = $("#button");
  var w = $("#wrapper");
  var l = $("#list");

  // w.height(l.outerHeight(true)); REMOVE THIS 

  b.click(function() {

    if (w.hasClass('open')) {
      w.removeClass('open');
      w.height(0);
    } else {
      w.addClass('open');
      w.height(l.outerHeight(true));
    }

  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 200ms;
  height: 0; /* <-- set this */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Toggle Expand/Collapse</button>
<!-- <div id="wrapper" class="open"> REMOVE THIS  -->
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome, thanks so much! that helps me understand it a bit more.

Comment: @NewLife - no problem, there's always a few approaches available, so happy to provide alternatives etc :)

Comment: is it possible to use the option 1 code in a more "generalised" way (using the 'this' code, or something similar)? 
I have 8 info boxes on my page and would rather not have to repeat the code 8 times for each box (with different var id's each time).

Answer (score 4):

you can use jquery `.toggle()` method

```
<button id="button">Toggle Expand/Collapse</button>
<div id="wrapper" class="open">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>  


$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#wrapper').toggle();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/11jzhf0r/)

**updated**
you can add the following `.css`

```
#wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
  display:none
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/11jzhf0r/1/)

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but jsfiddle is still loading it as expanded instead of hidden

Comment: it needs to load as collapsed (not expanded)

Answer (score 2):

## using CSS

You can accomplish this with just CSS:

```css
div#wrapper {
  transition: max-height 1000ms;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#toggle:not(:checked) ~ div#wrapper {
  max-height: 0;
}
#toggle:checked ~ div#wrapper {
  max-height: 200px;
}
#toggle:checked ~ label:after {
  content: "hide"
}
#toggle:not(checked) ~ label:after {
  content: "show"
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<label for="toggle"></label>

<div id="wrapper" class="open">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

## using JavaScript

You're pretty much there. Just use [`$.hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`$.show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) instead of [`$.height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).

A more succinct method would be [`$.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), however, which does the same as the below code.

```js
$(function() {
  var b = $("#button");
  var w = $("#wrapper");
  var l = $("#list");
  
  w.height(l.outerHeight(true));

  b.click(function() {
    if(w.hasClass("open")) {
      w.hide();
    } else {
      w.show()
    }
    w.toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 200ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button">Toggle Expand/Collapse</button>
<div id="wrapper" class="open">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply.  however, it's still showing the ul as default when the snippet is run

Comment: it needs to load as collapsed (not expanded)

Comment: @NewLife I added a CSS-only solution. If you want to have the original solution load the div collapsed, just add a `w.hide()`.

Answer (score 2):

jQuert toggle method will help you, if you want it hidden for the first time apply style like this -> style="display:none" If you want it visible then don't add this style

Basically what toggle function does is, if your component visible then hides it and if it is hidden then shows it...

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#wrapper').toggle();
})
```

below code will explain you better
http://jsfiddle.net/31zfvm2u/

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="button" onclick=sample();>Toggle Expand/Collapse</button>
<div id="wrapper" class="open">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

function sample()
{
$(#wrapper).toogle();
}
```