# Expand and collapse div element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, expand

I'm trying to expand and collapse a button included in side navigation bar.

Following the example given here [javascript expand/collapse button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523370/javascript-expand-collapse-button?rq=3), I tried to include a toggle expand and collapse button. But when I click on it, it shows an error and doesn't work as expected.

When clicked, it should display the list of items (in the example tried). In the real case, I want to include input field boxes.

[image]

Complete code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>
            Visualization
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.58.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/adf1f3a283.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            /* collapse-expand */
            $(function() {
              var b = $("#button");
              var w = $("#wrapper");
              var l = $("#list");
              b.click(function() {
                w.toggleClass('open'); /* <-- toggle the application of the open class on click */
              });
            });
            /* end of collaspe-expand */

            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                getExampleValue();
            });


        </script>
        <style>
            .graph-container {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                height: 100vh;
            }
            .main-panel {
                width: 100%;
                height: 800px;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }
            .side-panel {
                position: absolute;
                top: 80px;
                bottom: 0;
                right: -300px;
                width: 300px;
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
                transition: right 0.5s;
                overflow-y: auto;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .side-panel.open {
                right: 0;
            }

            .right-arrow {
                position: absolute;
                top: 20px;
                left: 20px;
                border-top: 20px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
                border-right: 20px solid #2196F3;
                cursor: pointer;
                transition: transform .5s ease-out;
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }

            .open .right-arrow{
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }

            .left-arrow {
                position: absolute;
                top: 20px;
                right: 20px;
                border-top: 20px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
                border-right: 20px solid #2196F3;
                cursor: pointer;
                transition: transform .5s ease-out;
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }

            .open .left-arrow {
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }

            {# Added Code for side bar  #}

            .sidenav {
              height: 100%;
              width: 250px;
              position: fixed;
              z-index: 3;
              top: 80px;
              left: -200px;
              background-color: #111;
              overflow-x: hidden;
              transition: 0.5s;
              padding-top: 60px;
            }

            /*.open .sidenav {
               left: -20px;
            }*/

            .sidenav.open {
               left: 0px;
            }

            .form{
              transition: 0.1s;
              opacity: 0;
            }

            .open .form{
              left: -20px;
              opacity: 1;
            }

            .sidenav a {
              padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 25px;
              color: #818181;
              display: block;
              transition: 0.3s;
            }

            .sidenav a:hover {
              color: #f1f1f1;
            }

            .sidenav .closebtn {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              right: 25px;
              font-size: 36px;
              margin-left: 50px;
            }

            #main {
                transition: margin-left .5s;
                padding: 16px;
                margin-left: 250px;
            }

            .form {
                opacity: 0;
                border-radius: 20px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                height: 500px;
                padding: 20px;
                width: inherit;
                font-size: 1.8rem;
            }

            .title{
                color: #eee;
                font-family: "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", Monaco, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
                font-size: 25px;
                font-weight: 400;
                padding-left: 15px;

            }

            .input-container {
                height: 50px;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                font-size: 1em;
            }

            .soura {
              margin-top: 40px;
            }

            .ic2 {
              margin-top: 30px;
            }

            .input {
              background-color: #303245;
              border-radius: 12px;
              border: 0;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              color: #eee;
              font-size: 18px;
              height: 100%;
              outline: 0;
              padding: 4px 20px;
              width: 100%;
            }

            .cut {
              background-color: black;
              border-radius: 10px;
              height: 20px;
              left: 20px;
              position: absolute;
              top: -20px;
              transform: translateY(0);
              transition: transform 200ms;
            }

            /*.input:focus ~ .cut,
            .input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .cut {
              transform: translateY(10px);
              height: 30px;
            }*/

            .arrowsize-cut{
                width: 115px;
            }

            .concentration-cut{
                width: 105px;
            }

            .example-cut{
                width: 140px;
            }

            .labelsize-cut{
                width: 80px;
            }

            .input:focus ~ .cut,
            .input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .cut {
              transform: translateY(8px);
            }

            .placeholder {
              color: #65657b;
              font-family: sans-serif;
              left: 20px;
              line-height: 14px;
              position: absolute;
              transform-origin: 0 50%;
              transition: transform 200ms, color 200ms;
              top: 20px;
            }

            .input:focus ~ .placeholder,
            .input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .placeholder {
              transform: translateY(-30px) translateX(10px) scale(0.75);
            }

            .input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .placeholder {
              color: #808097;
            }

            .input:focus ~ .placeholder {
              color: #dc2f55;
            }

            .submit {
              background-color: #08d;
              border-radius: 12px;
              border: 0;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              color: #eee;
              cursor: pointer;
              font-size: 18px;
              height: 30px;
              margin-top: 38px;
              outline: 0;
              text-align: center;
              width: 100%;
            }

            .submit:active {
              background-color: #06b;
            }

            /* Adding the button */

            @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
              .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
              .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
            }

            /* Code for download button */

            .hide {
                max-height: 0 !important;
            }

            .dropdown{
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: #65657B;
                border-radius: 500px;
                padding: 5px;
                /*top: -100px;*/
                float: left;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            .dropdown .title{
                margin: .3em .3em .3em .3em;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .dropdown .title .fa-angle-right{
                float: right;
                margin-right: .7em;
                transition: transform .3s;
            }

            .dropdown .menu{
                transition: bottom .5s ease-out;
                background-color: black;
                min-width: 18rem;
                /* bottom: 7.9em; */
                border:  solid white;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: absolute;
                font-size: 10px;
            }

            .dropdown .menu .option{
                margin: .1em .1em .1em .1em;
                margin-top: 0.3em;
                color: white;
                font-size: 10px;
            }

            .dropdown .menu .option:hover{
                background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            }

            .pointerCursor:hover{
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .rotate-90{
                transform: rotate(-90deg);
            }

            .clickable {
              cursor: pointer;
              text-decoration: underline;
              color: blue;
            }

            select#format-select {
                background-color: #65657B;
                color: #fff;
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 10px;
                border-radius: 7px;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .dropdown .download-button {
                background-color: #65657B;
                color: #000;
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 5px 45px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .dropdown .download-button i {
              margin-top: 6px;
            }

            .center-container {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                height: 10vh;
            }

             .title {
                text-align: center;
            }

            #network .modebar {
                top: 150px;
                left: 200px;
            }

            /* collapse-expand*/

            #wrapper {
              background: #ccc;
              overflow: hidden;
              transition: max-height 300ms;
              max-height: 0; /* <---hide by default */
            }

            #wrapper.open {
              max-height: 100px; /* <---when open, allow content to expand to take up as much height as it needs, up to e.g. 100px */
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "main" style="margin-left: 7rem;">

            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav open">
                <div class="left-arrow" onclick="toggleNav()"></div>
                <form class="form" id="myForm" action="{% url 'visualization' %}" method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}

                  <div class = "title">  <i class="fas fa-cog"></i> </div>
                  <div class="input-container soura">
                  <input id="examples" class="input" name="examples" placeholder=" " value="ex1" onclick="getExampleValue()"/>
                  <div class="cut example-cut"></div>
                  <label for="examples" class="placeholder">
                      Examples
                      <span id="example1" class="example" onclick="setExampleValue('ex1')"> #1</span>
                      <span id="example2" class="example" onclick="setExampleValue('ex2')"> #2</span>
                  </label>
                  </div>

                    <button id="button">Toggle Expand/Collapse</button>
                    <div class="input-container soura" id="wrapper">
                      <ul id="list">
                        <li>Item</li>
                        <li>Item</li>
                        <li>Item</li>
                        <li>Item</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>


                    <div class="center-container">
                        <div class='dropdown'>
                              <select id="format-select" class="pointerCursor">
                                <option value="png">PNG</option>
                                <option value="svg">SVG</option>
                                <option value="jpeg">JPEG</option>
                              </select>
                            <button class="download-button"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>


            <div class="graph-container">
                <div id="network" class="main-panel"></div>

            </div>

        <script>



            //read the data from the json file
            function getCookie(name) {
                const cookieValue = document.cookie
                    .split('; ')
                    .find(cookie => cookie.startsWith(name + '='));

                if (cookieValue) {
                    return decodeURIComponent(cookieValue.split('=')[1]);
                }
                return null;
            }

            async function getExampleValue() {
                const filename = document.getElementById("examples").value
                console.log("filename")
                console.log(filename)

                // Attach an event listener to the button
                var selection = document.getElementById('result-select').value;
                console.log("result-select")
                console.log(selection)

                var temp = {filename: filename, option: selection}

                const csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
                const url = "{% url 'visualization' %}"

                await fetch(url, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(temp)
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {


                    var downloadBtn = document.querySelector('.download-button');
                    downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                        var format = formatSelect.value;
                        console.log(format)
                        Plotly.toImage('network', {format: format, width: 800, height: 600})
                            .then(function (url) {
                                var link = document.createElement('a');
                                link.download = 'chart.' + format;
                                link.href = url;
                                link.click();
                            });
                    });
                })
            }
        </script>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
            let navState = true;
            function toggleNav(){
             if(navState){
               closeNav();
             }else{
                openNav();
             }
             navState = !navState;
            }

            function openNav() {
                document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.add("open");
                document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
            }

            function closeNav() {
                document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.remove("open");
                document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
            }

    </script>
</html>
```

Suggestions on including a field that will expand to display the contents and collapse when clicked will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on 19th line of your JavaScript code and in the function `getExampleValue()`. There is a variable called selection that is referencing from a element with id 'result-select', that is not available.

Therefore, first add the input or textarea element with `id='result-select'`. The error is causing because of the absence of that element.

19th Line :

```
var selection = document.getElementById('result-select').value; // Referring to an absent element
```